# MIPS Direct Mapped Cache for Arrays

Tags: caching, assembly, memory-management, mips, mips32

I need some clarity on how a direct mapped cache in MIPS works for an array. For example, for an array of ten items a[0] to a[9], and the following direct mapped cache configuration: Direct mapped cache with total cache size of 32 bytes and block size of 16 bytes. Each memory address is 32 bits.

Which would yield: 4 bits offset, 1 bit index, 27 bits tag

My cache would look like this:

```
| Index | Valid | Tag | W0 | W1 | W2 | W3 |
|   0   |   0   |     |    |    |    |    |
|   1   |   0   |     |    |    |    |    |
```

My question is, on my first load for a[0], I understand that in each cache index, we can store 4 words. Does this mean `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]` all gets loaded into the cache on load access for `a[0]`? So `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and `a[3]` will be a hit.

Or am I understanding it wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the alignment of `a[0]`.

Let's assume `a[0]` is at 0x10010000.  Then the block of 16 bytes that is loaded starts at 0x10010000 and goes thru 0x1001000F.

`a[0]` is at 0x10010000, `a[1]` is at 0x10010004, `a[2]` is at 0x10010008, and `a[3]` is at 0x1001000C — all in that cache line.

---

However, if `a[0]` is at 0x10010004, then the block of 16-bytes that is loaded is still the same block at 0x10010000, but now contains the word in front of `a[0]`, `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]`, but not `a[3]`.

However, if `a[0]` is at 0x10010008, then the block of 16-bytes that is loaded is still the same block at 0x10010000, but now contains the two words in front of `a[0]`, `a[0]`, `a[1]`, but not `a[2]` and not `a[3]`.

---

We're also assuming that the elements of `a` are 4 byte integers.  MIPS has an alignment requirement for integers but that is only 4 bytes, not 16 bytes.  So, there is no reason to presume that `a` is anything more than 4 byte aligned, unless we are told something more.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I guess the alignment matters a lot, and in this case they map out nicely (starts at 0000). Can I also quickly check that my calculations for my tag, index and offset are right? I sometimes find it hard to calculate these, because during my lecture I was given more information to derive those, but in my tutorial, they only gave me the 'total size of cache' and 'block size' (which I assume is the cache size?)

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  A direct mapped cache is the same as a one-way set associative cache.  So, we divide the total cache bytes (32) by 1 = 32, ((for 2-way we would divide by 2 here instead)), and then since the block size is 16 we determine there are only two index positions (0,1 = 1 bit) of 16 bytes in 32 bytes.